# SSL handshaking in Java

Tags: java, ssl

My Java client needs to access a resource that is served via a TLS connection. The resource provider uses a self-signed key, namely `MM_Base64.cer`. I imported their key into a Java keystore and a Java truststore.

For keystore, I issued

`keytool -import -keystore D:\mptkeystore.jks -file D:\MM_Base64.cer -alias mpt`

and the result is

```
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
Owner: CN=client, OU=huawei, O=huawei, L=shenzhen, C=CN
Issuer: CN=client, OU=huawei, O=huawei, L=shenzhen, C=CN
Serial number: 55702f20
Valid from: Thu Jun 04 17:27:36 MMT 2015 until: Sat May 11 17:27:36 MMT 2115
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  F5:8E:12:58:AC:97:53:CB:8B:B6:E2:DB:C3:F2:48:3D
         SHA1: F2:09:23:4C:9A:30:A6:4C:2D:F8:B0:F4:1D:06:41:5C:3A:3E:16:5A
         SHA256: 2B:51:BA:48:52:59:82:22:3C:E3:79:93:9E:C5:57:24:A5:9A:6E:08:A2:
7A:C6:FD:02:60:EB:3C:F2:14:53:AB
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

For trusrstore,

`keytool -import -file D:\MM_Base64.cer -alias mit -keystore D:\truststore.jks`

Result:

```
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
Owner: CN=client, OU=huawei, O=huawei, L=shenzhen, C=CN
Issuer: CN=client, OU=huawei, O=huawei, L=shenzhen, C=CN
Serial number: 55702f20
Valid from: Thu Jun 04 17:27:36 MMT 2015 until: Sat May 11 17:27:36 MMT 2115
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  F5:8E:12:58:AC:97:53:CB:8B:B6:E2:DB:C3:F2:48:3D
         SHA1: F2:09:23:4C:9A:30:A6:4C:2D:F8:B0:F4:1D:06:41:5C:3A:3E:16:5A
         SHA256: 2B:51:BA:48:52:59:82:22:3C:E3:79:93:9E:C5:57:24:A5:9A:6E:08:A2:
7A:C6:FD:02:60:EB:3C:F2:14:53:AB
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

Looks redundant but just in case, being redundant is necessary.

This is how the program gets executed:

```
java -jar CPS.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\mptkeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Ddeployment.security.SSLv2Hello=false -Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true
```

TLS v1 cannot be used with the service so I disabled it.

It looks as if the handshaking error still occurs. Does anyone see a problem with the way I am doing things?

Comment: Are you saying that the *server* you're talking to is using a certificate with a CN of `client`? That looks more like a client certificate, not a server certificate, since server certificates will need a CN that is the same as the domain name (e.g. www.example.org) you're using to access the site, at least for HTTPS.

Comment: I am developing a JavaSE client. The server is using `MM_Base64.cer`. They have shared the certificate file with us and we are importing the certificate into our client.

Comment: Terminology problems here. The server is using a self-signed *certificate.* Please fix your question so it makes sense.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot for your input. Your comment led me to the problem with the certificate. CN should be the IP address not client.

Answer (score 1):

For adding to truststore i think you would need to add

> -trustcacerts

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html has examples -

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts
-alias keyAlias
 -file server.cer
-keystore cacerts.jks
 -keypass changeit
-storepass changeit
```

Comment: That's taken care of by the `trust this certificate` question and response.